# "Best practice" for HBase data "serialization"

Tags: serialization, orm, hbase

Hi I am new to HBase and I wonder what is the best approach to serialize and store the data to HBase. Is there any convenient way how to transform "business objects" at application level to HBase objects (Put) - transformation to byte[]. I doubt that it has to be converted manually via helpers methods like .toByte etc.

What are the best practices and experiences?
I read about Avro, Thrift, n-orm, ...
Can someone share his knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the default Java API and enable compression on HDFS rather than using a framework for serializing / deserializing efficiently during RPC calls.

Apparently, updates like addition of a column to records in Avro/Thrift would be difficult as you are forced to delete and recreate. 
Secondly, I don't see support for Filters in thrift/avro. In case you need to filter data at the source.

My two cents .

For a ORM solution, kindly have a look at https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera .

Comment: I am more concern with the transformation of byte arrays to objects - back and forth. I would like to avoid of for every single object to convert it into byte[] field after field etc. So I would be curious to compare the possible solutions. If someone had that experience. Pros and cons etc.